# proving that the space of sequences $M\ni x=(x_j\ :\ j\in\Bbb N)\subset A$, where $A$ is a set, with a certain distance is a complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider the space $(M,d)$ of sequences $x=(x_j :\ j\in\Bbb N),\ x_j\in A~\forall j$, where $A$ is a set, with 
$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{\min\{j\in\Bbb N^*\ :\ x_j\ne y_j\}} 
&\text{if}~~~ x\ne y
\\0 &\text{if}~~~x=y
\end{cases}$$

**Question:** prove that $(M,d)$ is a complete metric space.

My attempt:

Suppose a sequence $(x^{(n)})\subset M$ satisfies $\forall\epsilon>0~\exists N\in\Bbb N~\forall m,n\ge N~d(x^{(n)},x^{(m)})\le\epsilon$ i.e. $\frac{1}{\min\{j\in\Bbb N^*~:x^{(n)}_j\ne x^{(m)}_j\}}\le\epsilon$

I know there is a method where we do an analogy between our sequence and a sequence in $(\Bbb R,|\_|)$, which is complete, and the property of convergence can be passed on to $(x^{(n)})$ but I need a hint

Comment: have you already shown that it is a metric space?

Comment: @supinf yes I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to understand what $x^{(n)} \to x$ means in this space, where $x^{(n)} \in M$ is a sequence , and $x \in M$.

What it means is this : for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $d(x^{(n)},x) < \epsilon$. In other words, for all $n > N$ and $m < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, we have $x_m^{(n)} = x_m$.

---

Now, I will leave you with points to fill.

- Suppose $x^{(n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
- Fix $k\in N$. Show that $x_k^{(n)}$ is an eventually constant sequence(in $n$) using the definition above. (A sequence is said to be eventually constant if there exists $l$ so that every term of the sequence is $l$ after some point)
- Call the constant which $x_k^{(n)}$ converges to, as $x_k$. Now, using $x_k$ we define a sequence $x$.
- Show that $x \in M$ and that $x^{(n)}  \to x$.

Comment: I think it would be preferable if you would use the notation from John Cataldo for the double indices.

Comment: I will change the notation shortly. There, done.

Comment: Why should the sequence become constant in $n$ after a while?

Comment: Let $x^{(n)}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Fix $k \in \mathbb N$. Then, take $\epsilon = \frac 1k$. By definition of Cauchy, there exists $N$ such that $m,n \geq N$ implies $d(x^{(m)}, x^{(n)}) < \epsilon = \frac 1k$. Now, $d(x^{(m)},x^{(n)})$ is the reciprocal of the first position at which $x^{(m)}$ and $x^{(n)}$ differ. If this is smaller than $\frac 1k$, then that means that $x^{(m)}$ and $x^{(n)}$ don't differ at the $k$th position, but rather some position after it. Now, since this is true for $m,n \geq N$, we see that if $n >N$ then the $k$th position of $x^{(n)}$ remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:**

If two elements $x,y$ are close (with respect to the metric $d$) this means that the first few coefficients $x_j,y_j$
are the same.

using the definition of a Cauchy sequence, it can be seen that
for each $k$ there is an $N=N(k)$ such that for all $n\geq N(k)$ we have

$$
x_j^{(n)} = x_j^{(N(k))}
\quad
\text{for all};
j=1,\dots,k.
$$

Note that $N(k)$ can be chosen such that $N:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is an increasing function.

Then the limit point of $(x^{(n)})$ will be
$$
 y:= (y_k : k\in\mathbb N) := ( x_k^{N(k)} ).
$$
It remains to show that $(x^{(n)})$ actually converges to $x$.